# What is the format for a mono channel 16bit PCM

Tags: pcm

How are mono channel 16bit PCM arranged in LSB and MSB since it will no longer be `[LEFT LSB][LEFT MSB][RIGHT LSB][RIGHT MSB]`

EDIT
I don't understand the reason for the downvote but to better explain the question...
In a stereo channel (LEFT and RIGHT channel) 16bit PCM, 4 byte represent a sample stored as `[LEFT CHANNEL LSB][LEFT CHANNEL MSB][RIGHT CHANNEL LSB][RIGHT CHANNEL MSB]`. But in a mono channel 16bit PCM there are no left or right channel, how are the `LSB` and `MSB` stored?

Comment: try playing it back both ways. the wrong way will sound horrible.

Comment: Upvoted because I found the downvote unfair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my confusion after hours of thinking! The confusion started from the thought that since the PCM is 16bit, a sample will always be 4 bytes whether it is `Mono` or `Stereo` but I was wrong! A Stereo sample will be 4 bytes when a Mono sample will be 2 bytes so it is stored as `[LSB][MSB]` for a sample!